# CodeBlocks files not recognized in project

Tags: c++, header, codeblocks

I've been using code blocks for a long time, but never really made my programs into actual code blocks projects. I tried to do it today, and I kept getting errors due to code blocks not recognizing my files. Here is what I have : ---->
[CodeBlocks Include Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBC3O.png)

When I try to buiild my project I get that cout,cin and my class objects are not defined in my menu.cpp file. So I can only guess code blocks is not properly handling the files.

I would love if someone could help me out as to why this is happening.

Thanks a ton in advance :)

Comment: why are you including .cpp instead of .h ?

Comment: also please add [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and not screenshots.. its much more comfortable to check the code in text than opening external link to screenshot - and the error message is not visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to buiild my project I get that cout,cin and my class objects are not defined in my menu.cpp file.

That's because they're not. You `#include`d neither `iostream` nor `class.h` in `menu.cpp`, so you can't access the declarations therein.

Note that Code Blocks (just like any properly set up build tools) will compile each cpp file separately. This means that not only will it compile menu.cpp as part of the compilation of main.cpp (because you include it), it will also compile it on its own. In the latter case the includes from main.cpp will not be available, so menu.cpp needs its own includes.

This also means that once it does compile (i.e. once you added the includes), you'll get a linker error because the definitions from menu.cpp are now defined twice (once in main.o -- because you included menu.cpp in main.cpp -- and once in menu.o). That's the reason why you should never include cpp files into each other.

PS: This is unrelated to your problem, but it's considered bad practice to use `using namespace` in a header file. You should put that in your cpp files instead (if you want to use it at all). You should also put the `#include <iostream>` in those files where you actually need it, rather than the header file.

Comment: Thanks sepp2k, for all the useful information you gave me. I ran my project without including the cpp file and it worked. I now also know why it didn't before. Thanks a ton. 
I'll take into account what you said about namespace and iostream as well. 
Thank you and have a wonderful day :)